# Javascript Iteration to display custom list with pause/stop jquery fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, fadein, fadeout

I have an array that is constantly being updated, and needs to display the items in the array 5 at a time.  Sometimes there are more than 5 elements in the array, sometimes there are less.  If there are more than 5 elements in the array, then I need to cycle them 5 at a time.  For example, if there are 10 elements, I want to fade in 1-5, then fade out 1-5, then fade in 5-10. I have this working, and updating, however, if there are only 4 news articles available after the data update, it still fades in and out 1-4, over and over.  I need to always fade in the first articles, and if there are less than the numberToShow, don't fade out, just update.

I have tried clearInterval, but that stops updating. I tried .stop().fadeOut(); but then the fade in keeps occurring. I tried .stop().fadeOut(); with .stop().fadeIn(); but the data never fades in.  Should I pass the array in to display it, and cycle in there?

For testing, this is simulated with using the date.  Every 8 seconds it should update the the data with an updated number. If there are 4 articles, fade in, and update the Date.now() number, but never fade out. If there are 10 articles, fade in and update each cycle.

```
var numberToShow = 5;
var newsArray = [];
var startRow = 0;
var endRow = 0;

 function getData() {
  // Simulate the data changing using date.
  newsArray = [Date.now(), "News article 1", "News article 2", "News article 3", "News article 4", 
  "News article 5", "News article 6", "News article 7", "News article 8", "News article 9"];

  showNews(numberToShow);
 }

// Fade out the results for the next cycle
setInterval(function() {
 $("span.text").fadeOut({
  duration: 800
 });
 setTimeout(
   function() {
   getData();
   },
  (800)
 );
}, 8000);

// Update the data
function updateData() {
  getData();
  setTimeout(updateData, 6000);
}

// Display the results
function showNews() {

if (endRow >= newsArray.length) {
  startRow = 0;
}
endRow = startRow + numberToShow;

if (endRow >= newsArray.length) {
  endRow = newsArray.length;
}
  var results = "";
  for (var k = startRow; k < endRow; k++) {
     results += "<span class='text' style='display:none;'>" + newsArray[k] + "</span><br>";
  }
 startRow = startRow + numberToShow;

 document.getElementById('showResults').innerHTML = results;

 $("span.text").fadeIn({
  duration: 800
 });
}




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showResults"></div>
```

Comment: All of these side effects are creating trouble for you because they are difficult to track down. This is a great example of where custom events can be helpful. Create a custom event in which the handler fades the old out and new in. Then, only trigger the custom event when necessary rather than in timers and intervals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent

Comment: Why can't you count the array with .length? If the length is more than 4, do whatever effect you want to do etc. if not, just fadeIn()

Comment: Because if I count the array to not fade out, then the fade in will keep getting called at each update.  And the fade in will remove the data, and fade it back in.  If I remove the fade in as well, the data never fades in to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

While previous answer works fine - this one could be more like the case in your description...
Short description of the idea:

1. show list or the part of it.
2. if list is longer - repeat (go to step 1 in a couple of secs to show another part of the list)
3. when update comes - anytime - start again with new array

And working example (removed unneeded code and added button to help with tests):

```js
var
  numberToShow = 5,
  newsArray = [],
  startRow = 0,
  endRow = 0,
  $results = $("#showResults"),
  timer;

function getData() {
  // Simulate the data changing
  newsArray = [Date.now()];
  // add random number of items
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+1;
  for(var i=0; i<j; i++){
    newsArray.push('News article '+i);
  }
  // add one more item named "last"
  newsArray.push('Last News article');

  startCycle();
}

function startCycle() {
  startRow = 0;
  endRow = 0;
  $results.fadeOut(800, function(){
    renderList();
  });
}

function renderList() {
  if (endRow >= newsArray.length) {
    startRow = 0;
  }
  endRow = startRow + numberToShow;
  if (endRow > newsArray.length) {
    endRow = newsArray.length;
  }
  var results = "";
  for (var k = startRow; k < endRow; k++) {
    results += "<span class='text'>" + newsArray[k] + "</span><br>";
  }
  startRow = startRow + numberToShow;
  $results.html(results);

  $results.fadeIn(800, function(){
    nextCycle();
  });
}

function nextCycle() {
  // start cycling only if there is more results to be shown
  if(newsArray.length > numberToShow){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      $results.fadeOut(800, function(){
        renderList();
      });
    }, 4000);
  }
}

// update on request
function updateData() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  $results.stop();
  getData();
}
// add button for tests
$results.before(
  $('<button/>').text('Update now').click(function(){
    updateData();
  })
)

getData();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showResults"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry but I am struggling to understand this.  The data does not fade in initially when renderList() loads on body.  We will need to fade in the text $("span.text").fadeIn opposed to the div that contains the results, and need to keep updating the data every 60 seconds.  I couldn't get the example to work.  Did I miss something?

Comment: to run the first cycle (initial run) you need to run `getData()` ...and to make it update every 60 secs - just use `setInterval` to run `updateData()` every 60 sec. Thats all... And never animate 5 elements if you can animate 1 with the same effect.

Comment: @Mike PS. hope you know that blue button "Run code snippet" under the code - is running the example?

Comment: I am sorry, but the "Run code snippet" is not working in Safari for me.  Seeing your comment, I tried in chrome and it works, but the update needs to occur behind the scenes, without restarting the cycle.  The updated data should be reflected when the loop cycles again.

Comment: If there are less than the numberToShow items, and it does not fade out, the data should just update on the interval.  Otherwise, it will update on the next fadein/out cycle.

Comment: @Mike This forum is not to make others to do your job - it is just to help you to do it yourself. Don't want to restart the cycle - it's really easy - just move couple of lines in this code. Or just set the timeout to 4400 - it should be exactly 10 fade-in/outs when update comes after 60seconds.

Comment: And @Mike please remember - people who help you here on StackOverflow expect to recieve some points for their help. Then if you think one of the answers (or a little comment like this one) helps you to get closer to your goal - mark it as "useful" by clicking "arrow up" button on the left side of it to reward the author.

Comment: I am sorry, but if you look at the original question, I clearly made a good attempt at this, and got this working, with the exception of pausing the fading if and only if there are less than the amount to display. I plan on rewarding contributors once I get this working. Your solution was the closest, but I am no closer as it still fades in and out when less than NumberToShow is returned.  Set the array to newsArray = [Date.now(), "News article 2", "News article 3"]; and it fades in and out the same 3 articles, that is where I need advice.

Comment: When solution matches your needs you marking it as "Solution", when comment or solution moved you one little step closer just learned you anything else - you rate it up. This is what we all do here. Some people treat it same as "like it" on the FB. ...if you don't want to fade just move fade into `if` statement - just read the code and then play with it - best way to learn - really.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - not sure what exactly you tried to do - but you will easily change my code into anything you need
...lets start with clear algorithm:

1. getData
2. fade out if list is visible ...then continue to step 3.
3. render next portion of items from array
4. fade in if list is not visible ...then go to step 5.
5. wait a while...
6. check if all items has been shown (if not - show next portion with step 2, if so - update data with step 1)

hope the the code will give you a chance to adopt it to your needs:

```js
var
  numberToShow = 5,
  newsArray = [],
  startRow = 0,
  endRow = 0,
  $results = $("#showResults"),
  visible = false,
  timer;

function fadeInIfNeeded(callback) {
  var is_visible = visible;
  visible = true;
  if(is_visible){
    callback();
  }else{
    $results.fadeIn(800, callback);
  }
}

function fadeOutIfNeeded(callback) {
  var is_visible = visible;
  visible = false;
  if(is_visible){
    $results.fadeOut(800, callback);
  }else{
    callback();
  }
}

function getData() {
  // Simulate the data changing
  newsArray = [Date.now()];
  // add random number of items
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+2;
  for(var i=1; i<j; i++){
    newsArray.push('News article '+i);
  }
  // add one more item named "last"
  newsArray.push('Last News article');

  startCycle();
}

function startCycle() {
  startRow = 0;
  endRow = 0;
  fadeOutIfNeeded(function(){
    renderList();
  });
}

function renderList() {
  if (endRow >= newsArray.length) {
    startRow = 0;
  }
  endRow = startRow + numberToShow;
  if (endRow > newsArray.length) {
    endRow = newsArray.length;
  }
  var results = "";
  for (var k = startRow; k < endRow; k++) {
    results += "<span class='text'>" + newsArray[k] + "</span><br>";
  }
  startRow = startRow + numberToShow;
  $results.html(results);

  fadeInIfNeeded(function(){
    nextCycle();
  });
}

function nextCycle() {
  // every portion of data will be seen for 6 + 0.8 + 0.8 = 7.6 sec
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    if(startRow >= newsArray.length){
      // if all items has been shown - get new data (update)
      getData();
    }else{
      // if there is more to show - fade out and render
      fadeOutIfNeeded(function(){
        renderList();
      });
    }
  }, 6000);
}

getData();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showResults"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modern view of how to implement your use case. Please note there
is not a single global variable and all DOM changes (side effects) occur in a single function.

You describe a constantly changing array. This code produces that array of integers
with one remarkable difference. After the data is set/retrieved, a [Custom Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)
is produced and fired. That event carries the changed/updated array.

```js
function newData(data) {  // Random size of array (between 1-15)
  const previousLength = data.length;
  // ~50% of the time the array grows, otherwise it shrinks
  data.length = (Math.random() > .5)?
    data.length + Math.ceil(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1) :
    Math.ceil(Math.random() * (4 - 1) + 1);
  for (let i = previousLength; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (15 - 1) + 1);
  }
  let dataEvent = new CustomEvent('gotData', { detail: data});
  document.getElementById('showResults').dispatchEvent(dataEvent);
}
```

Your question describes what is the need for a custom [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) that provides no more than 5
array elements for each iteration. The following code provides a [Generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) that follows
JavaScript's [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) by returning a result with a `.value` property
containing an array of no more than 5 elements and a `.done` property containing a Boolean indicating if there
is no futher data. The `yield` statement returns data or the `return` statement results in
`.done` being set to `true` to indicate there is no further data. (see the MDN articles for details)

```js
function* nextSet(data = [], numberToShow = 5) {
  let current = [];
  let currentStart = 0;
  while (true) {
    [current] = [data.slice(currentStart, currentStart + numberToShow)];
    if (currentStart < data.length) {
      yield current;
    } else {
      return;
    }
    currentStart += numberToShow;
  }
}
```

With the data and iterator in place this code starts off the procession. Set up
an event listener for the custom event, then get some mock data (starting with an
empty array):

```js
document.getElementById('showResults').addEventListener('gotData', doDOM);
newData([]);
```

All the DOM work is done in the event callback function below (`doDOM()`).
First create an iterator from the Generator Function.
Then start the interval timer so that we can repeatedly call `.next()` on the iterator.
Please note how dead-simple the animation actually is with
a bit of rethinking the approach to the entire problem. If `result` is undefined
then cancel the interval timer, mock more data and repeat the process with the updated array.

```js
function doDOM(event) {
  const data = event.detail;
  const iterator = nextSet(data); // create iterator from Generator
  let text = '';
  let page = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(()=>{
    page++;
    let result = iterator.next().value;
    if(result) {
      text = `Array size: ${data.length} (Page ${page}) -- ${JSON.stringify(result)}`;
      // Dead simple animations...
      $(event.target).fadeOut(1000, () => {
        event.target.innerText = text;
        $(event.target).fadeIn(1000);
      });
    } else {
      event.target.innerText += " ----> getting more data..."
      // all done, so kill this one
      clearInterval(interval);
      // Mock new data arrival
      newData(data);
      return;
    }
  }, 5000);
}
```

I do realize this seems to be a mile off from your question. But this answer addresses the whole
puzzle rather than just one bit.

```js
/**
 * A Generator function to produce number of data elements
 */
function* nextSet(data = [], numberToShow = 5) {
  let current = [];
  let currentStart = 0;
  while (true) {
    [current] = [data.slice(currentStart, currentStart + numberToShow)];
    if (currentStart < data.length) {
      yield current;
    } else {
      return;
    }
    currentStart += numberToShow;
  }
}

/**
 * CustomEvent Handler - fired when new data is received
 *
 * DOM manipulations
 * All side effects are contained within one function
 * @parm Event - contains detail with data
 */
function doDOM(event) {
  const data = event.detail;
  const iterator = nextSet(data); // create iterator from Generator
  let text = '';
  let page = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    page++;
    let result = iterator.next().value;
    if (result) {
      text = `Array size: ${data.length} (Page ${page}) -- ${JSON.stringify(result)}`;
      // Dead simple animations...
      $(event.target).fadeOut(1000, () => {
        event.target.innerText = text;
        $(event.target).fadeIn(1000);
      });
    } else {
      event.target.innerText += " ----> That's it! Getting more data..."
      // all done, so kill this one
      clearInterval(interval);
      // Mock new data arrival
      newData(data);
      return;
    }
  }, 5000);
}

// Array that is either growing or changing on each call
function newData(data) { // Random size of array (between 1-15)
  const previousLength = data.length;
  // ~50% of the time the array grows, otherwise it shrinks
  data.length = (Math.random() > .5) ?
    data.length + Math.ceil(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1) :
    Math.ceil(Math.random() * (4 - 1) + 1);
  for (let i = previousLength; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (15 - 1) + 1);
  }
  let dataEvent = new CustomEvent('gotData', {
    detail: data
  });
  document.getElementById('showResults').dispatchEvent(dataEvent);
}

document.getElementById('showResults').addEventListener('gotData', doDOM);
newData([]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <main id="showResults">Welcome! ----> waiting for data...</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Expand the code snippet to see this work.